# How can I make a value-aware combo box in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Combo boxes in Flex are really awkward to use if you have objects in them addressed by properties, in my experience. In Flex 3.5 we had a working extension to the combo box that would populate a `selectedValue` property (and allow changing the `selectedIndex` by same).

Here's a quick example of what using one of these looks like:

```
<c:ValueComboBox valueField="country_code">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        public function get selectedCountry(): String {
            return this.selectedValue; // This property is added by ValueComboBox
        }

        public function set selectedCountry(v: String): void {
            this.selectedValue = v;
        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <c:dataprovider>
        <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <mx:Object label="Canada" country_code="ca"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </c:dataprovider>
</c:ValueComboBox>
```

However, this has stopped working in Flex 4. What's happening is that our existing component drove its changes by overriding the `set selectedIndex()` function, which is no longer called when the combo box's selected index changes (wtf?).

Is there a working value-aware combobox implementation for Flex 4?

For information purposes, here is the base value combo box class. https://gist.github.com/5639c7b2439b03748e2e

Answer (score 2):

Flex 4 ComboBox now uses `userProposedSelectedIndex` property to store temporal value of selected index till ComboBox closes. And then selectedIndex property doesn't set with `selectedIndex` but with calling of `setSelectedIndex` method with the following signature:

```
mx_internal function setSelectedIndex(value:int, dispatchChangeEvent:Boolean = false):void
```

I suggest you should override this method to make sure selected index is setting properly.

Hope this helps.